# AngularJS ajax form submit with submit input

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a form which having stepy wizard.For working stepy wizard,it is must to use input submit button not a button.So I am  using submit button,but while clicking submit button it is redirecting to main page.
My code

```
<form action="#" id="wizard" class="form-horizontal"  ng-submit="abc($event)">
   <!-- Step 1 -->
   <fieldset title="Step 1">
      <legend>Registration</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_house_number'); ?></label>
         <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"  required="required" ng-model="newItem.housenumber"/></div>
         <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_house_name'); ?></label>
         <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"  required="required" ng-model="newItem.housename"/></div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset title="Step 2">
      <legend>Registration</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_place'); ?></label>
      <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"  required="required" ng-model="newItem.place"/></div>
      <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_land_mark'); ?></label>
      <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"   ng-model="newItem.language"/></div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset title="Step 3">
      <legend><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_fac'); ?></legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="newItem.electricity"  value="electricity" /><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_electricty'); ?>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset title="Step 4">
      <legend>Agriculture</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="newItem.cocunut"  value="cocunut" /><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_cocunut'); ?>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset title="Step 5">
      <legend> Other</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_get_any_help'); ?></label>
         <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"   ng-model="newItem.help"/></div>
         <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_source'); ?></label>
         <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"   ng-model="newItem.source"/></div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" class="finish btn-success btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and this is my controller

```
mahalPlus.controller('familyRegistrationController', function($scope) {

  $scope.abc = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('submitted');
  };

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `preventDefault` is redundant, see [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSubmit).  You'll just need to remove the `action` attribute.

> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page) but only if the form does not contain an action attribute.

Instead, add `ng-app` to the appropriate HTML Element and ensure that your controller is properly loaded.

I've created a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sPSSPLsWrCOhynGFgZJs?p=preview), where you can see the changes I've suggested.

Comment: I am using routing for my application, ``.when('/family-registration', {
      templateUrl: 'api/index.php/templates/family_registration',
      controller: 'familyRegistrationController'
    })`` and I have the function defined inside the controller. Everything working excluding this one.

Answer (score 2):

1- remove action

2- remove $event from ng-submit="abc($event)"

3- You better think about your using of PHP in your tags , this is not a good Idea:(

Answer (score 0):

Believe you can just remove the action on the form.

Comment: Now the form is not redirecting. But the alert also not working..! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the controller reference to your form tag?

```
    <form id="wizard" class="form-horizontal"  ng-submit="abc($event)" 
ng-controller="familyRegistrationController">
```

Comment: Yes i have that in html body itself

Comment: please post your complete code, otherwise its very difficult to answer the question.

Comment: I am using routing for my application, .when('/family-registration', { templateUrl: 'api/index.php/templates/family_registration', controller: 'familyRegistrationController' }) and I have the function defined inside the controller. Everything working excluding this one.